# WM_Concat OR listagg

Tags: oracle, netsuite

My requirement is to either use NetSuite's version of wm_concat (ns_concat) OR Listagg filtering for unique records AND controlling the order of the list returned.

Because this is within NetSuite ideally I would list to wrap listagg within a distinct case statement, but cannot figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Do you mean a case formula to filter out the unique records ?

Comment: I can already filter out the unique records in a case formula, problem is I can't control the order of the list returned.

Comment: If you're using Netsuite saved search filters then I guess there is an option of sort.